# Where is 'time spent' shown in Eclipse Mylyn?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, mylyn, eclipse-luna

I cannot find where time spent is in Eclipse Luna with Mylyn.

According to http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui%2FMylyn%2FFAQ%2FTask-List.html, it is in the "Personal Planning" tab when looking at an item in Mylyn.

However, I see no such tab:

(screenshot of an open Mylyn item for me: http://cl.ly/image/2v0t2e0i2k3P)

I thought maybe it was related to my use of the GitHub Mylyn connector but creating a local task also does not display this information.

To be clear: I can activate/de-activate a task and I can set the estimated number of hours, but I cannot figure out how to simply view what time has been spent so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently didn't have all the necessary Mylyn dependencies installed. Simply installing the "GitHub Integration" (which included some Mylyn dependencies) wasn't enough.

I uninstalled everything related to Mylyn from Eclipse, including the GitHub connector and reinstalled just the base Mylyn package. I then went to Preferences -> Mylyn -> Tasks and ensured the "Time Tracking" section was there (it wasn't previously), and *then* I installed the GitHub connector.

I had to re-make all the GitHub-related Task Repositories and Queries as well.